# How to import a module from Python

Tags: python, import, module

I'm trying to import a class called dataFrame from a script called dataFrame.py that is in the same folder of the script that I'm trying to import it that is called Cutoff.
When I'm trying to import it I got this message:

"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modules'"

this how my project is organized:

```
Project
└───modules
    │
    └───planilhas
        └───components
                cutoff.py
                dataFrame.py
                gko.py
                gko_24.py
                gko_25.py
```

This how I trying to import it:

```
from modules.planilhas.components.dataFrame import DataFrame
import pandas as pd # pandas has no problem to be imported, ignore it

class Cutoff(DataFrame):
    pass
```

Where is the problem of my code? How do I import modules from Python in the right way?
Please, can someone give me a hand? Thanks!

Comment: To import package it needs to have a `__init__.py`. On all levels.

Comment: If you're trying to import it from `cutoff.py` which is in the same directory, then try `from dataFrame import DataFrame`.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's in the same folder, try just `from dataFrame import DataFrame`